# Is it possible to substitute ListView for a ScrollView when creating a SearchView?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I’m trying to follow a tutorial on creating a `SearchView` to search for specific songs in my music app. I was stuck at the part where the video used `SearchView` and `ListView`, whereas I wanted to use `SearchView` and *`ScrollView`* (in `ConstraintLayout`).

```
SearchView mySearchView;
ScrollView myList; // supposed to be ListView myList
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Everything goes fine until I reach setting adapters:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySearchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    myList = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    list= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Rising Hope");
    list.add("Would Look Perfect");
    list.add("Santa Baby");
    list.add("Thinking Out Loud");
    list.add("Iconic");
    list.add("Finesse");
    list.add("Dreamin");
    list.add("bad vibes forever");
    list.add("Kirakira Days");
    list.add("Shape Of You");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter); **(setAdapter was red here)
    mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
}
```

I'm wondering what I can change for my substitution from `ListView` into `ScrollView`, since my songs are all in `ConstraintLayout`, inside of a `ScrollView`, and I do not wish to take that view away.